# Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump straight to Apps?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I was looking for such shortcut but so far I could not find it... Does anyone know if it actually exists at all, or does not?

At the moment, my typical "path" to it is: <kbd>Win</kbd> then click on the <kbd>↓</kbd> at the bottom-left corner. I need a way to go straight to Apps with a single combination of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

Go to your desktop and right-click on the Taskbar.  Click on "Properties".  A window will pop up, with tabs across the top.  go to the "Navigation" tab.

Go down and click the checkbox that says *"Show the Apps view automatically when I go to Start"*.  Click OK.

Now, when you click on the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, you will go straight to the Apps page.  If wish to see the regular start screen, just click the up-arrow in the bottom-left corner.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

there no Direct way is available to reach any app on computer but you can Reach direct at Desktop by pressing window + D then go to direct app or do one thing you should make shoutcut of this map near a window icon

Comment: Well, I do not want to have all the apps on my desktop! :) This is the main reason why I need the shortcut. Commonly used apps I already have in my desktop and/or the panel...